# Custom JSON serialization/deserialization to read property in multiple possible formats

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My application reads JSON files created using a format like this:

```
{
  "myProperty": {complex JSON here}
}
```

```cs
class MyClass
{
   public MyChildClass MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

I need to change the way the class works, so that it looks like this instead:

```cs
class MyClass
{
   public MyNewChildClass MyNewProperty {get; set;}
}
```

and I need to be able to support files created in the older format, but also support a file if it was created using the new format.

I have the code to convert a `MyChildClass` object into a `MyNewChildClass` object, but how can I set up the serialization so that the object can deserialize the old format, changing the property name and type from `MyChildClass MyProperty` to  `MyNewChildClass MyNewProperty` AND just use the new format when serializing AND deserialize using the new format if that is what the JSON file contains?

Comment: Add both properties.... if a property is missing. It will be set up with a null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use both properties, the json will work for both, new and old.

```
class MyClass
{
   [JsonPropert("myProperty")]
   public MyChildClass MyProperty {get; set;}

   [JsonProperty("myNewProperty")] // -> Remember, case matters.
   public MyNewChildClass MyNewProperty {get; set;}
}
```

When you deserialize the class, add a check to see which is not null and work with that (different methods for each i guess). This should help you keep the breaking change to a minimum.

BTW>. if you have the code that converts the new to the old or vice versa, you can check if the value of old is null, then run that process/method you have to convert new to old and continue on with the object. Remember, it would have to be After the deserialization,

```
var properties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>("data");
if (properties.MyNewProperty == null) 
{
   properties = myMethodToConvertOldToNew(properties);
}

public MyClass myMethodToConvertOldToNew(MyClass)
{
  if (properties.New == null)
  {
     properties.New = ConversionMethod(properties.Old, properties.New);
     // dont have to, but,
     properties.Old = null;
  }
  return properties.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a private property to your class that will set your new property:

```
class MyClass
{
   [JsonProperty]
   private MyChildClass MyProperty { set => MyNewProperty = YourConversionMethod(value); }

   public MyNewChildClass MyNewProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The `JsonProperty` attribute will ensure that the private setter is used.